# Enable "mouse over event" for unthemed custom drawn button

Tags: c, winapi, button, custom-controls, mouseover

I have a custom drawn button. I enabled Visual Styles and then, just because I don't want this particular button to be themed, I used `SetWindowTheme(hwndCustomDrawnButton, L" ", L" ");` to disable themes for it just after its creation in the `WM_CREATE` message. The code for the button drawing is this:

```
case WM_NOTIFY:
{
    LPNMHDR item = (LPNMHDR)lParam;
    if (item->idFrom == 13 && item->code == NM_CUSTOMDRAW)
    {
        LPNMCUSTOMDRAW item_draw = (LPNMCUSTOMDRAW)item;
        if (item_draw->uItemState & CDIS_SELECTED)
        {
            SetDCBrushColor(item_draw->hdc, RGB(91, 173, 236));
            SelectObject(item_draw->hdc, GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH));
            SetDCPenColor(item_draw->hdc, RGB(91, 173, 236));
            SelectObject(item_draw->hdc, GetStockObject(DC_PEN));
        }
        else
        {
            SetDCBrushColor(item_draw->hdc, RGB(0, 125, 195));
            SelectObject(item_draw->hdc, GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH));
            SetDCPenColor(item_draw->hdc, RGB(0, 125, 195));
            SelectObject(item_draw->hdc, GetStockObject(DC_PEN));
        }
        // Here I draw rectangle and text...
        return CDRF_SKIPDEFAULT;
    }
}
break;
```

I tried handling the case when `uItemState` is `CDIS_HOT` but it doesn't work (I suppose it's because I disabled themes for this control). **Is there a way to change the appearance of this button when the mouse is over it?** I mean the exact scenario I obtain if I don't disable theming and I keep handling the case when `uItemState` is `CDIS_HOT` in the `WM_NOTIFY`. I tried to look over the web and I only found `TrackMouseEvent` function which was hard to understand for me. If that is a valid method to solve my problem, please can anybody provide me a code sample or a tutorial where this function is well explained?

I use plain C (no mfc or anything else) with Visual Studio on Windows 8.1. My application will be available from Windows 7 on.
Thanks!

Comment: Try if this CP article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/359/Capturing-the-Mouse helps.

Comment: Thanks! I read the article but it implements the function in a WindowProc which I don't have for my button, I only have one for my main window which is parent of the button itself.

Comment: You can subclass the button procedure. See http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/42062-win32-button-subclassingtrackmouseeventwm-mousemovewm-mouseleave-and-wm-mousehover/

Comment: You can request mouse hover notifications for any window (e.g. a button). It's a simple matter of filling in a [TRACKMOUSEEVENT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645604.aspx) and calling [TrackMouseEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646265.aspx).

Comment: Subclassing the button and creating a TRACKMOUSEEVENT structure looking at tutorials solved the problem. I will open another topic because the general problems I have aren't solved at all. Thanks to @Frankie_C.